# Not able to deploy my MEAN project using AWS - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, mean-stack

I have been trying to deploy my personal website using E2 AWS - Ubuntu 14.04.

I have a method that works 100% of the time for a smaller MEAN projects from the coding bootcamp, but for this personal project, I am constantly getting the 502 Gateway error:

> 502 Bad Gateway | nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

In the browser console,

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502
>   (Bad Gateway)

Here is the link to my personal website that is displaying the current error:

> http://52.38.252.146/

Here is the link to the source code

> https://github.com/fobbytommy/personal_website

Could someone guide me to a right direction on deploying this?
Like 1.) is it because of my favicon.ico? 2.) is it because I am trying to use Awesome Font dependencies? 3.) The file is too big? (it's less than 7 mb)

I just don't understand why it is happening to this MEAN project when I can deploy other MEAN project fine without any problems.

Thank you so much for your help.